# How do I filter out only the hash tagged word from this list and output to a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My input File contains the below list stores as a txt file

```
[(u'#Brexit', 823), (u'#brexit', 166), (u'#Brexitchaos', 135), (u'#StopBrexit', 63), (u'#EU', 46), (u'#BREXIT', 29), (u'#DavidDavis', 28), (u'#UK', 21), (u'#Remain', 20), (u'#BrexitReports', 17)]
```

I want to filter out the hash tagged words to a new txt file.

My Expected output is : **Output.txt**

```
Brexit
brexit
Brexitchaos
StopBrexit
EU
BREXIT
DavidDavis
UK
Remain
BrexitReports
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a regex. `"(?<=#)[^']+"` in this case, which means `as many characters as possible, after a '#' and until '`:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "[(u'#Brexit', 823), (u'#brexit', 166), (u'#Brexitchaos', 135), (u'#StopBrexit', 63), (u'#EU', 46), (u'#BREXIT', 29), (u'#DavidDavis', 28), (u'#UK', 21), (u'#Remain', 20), (u'#BrexitReports', 17)]"
>>> re.findall("(?<=#)[^']+", text)
['Brexit', 'brexit', 'Brexitchaos', 'StopBrexit', 'EU', 'BREXIT', 'DavidDavis', 'UK', 'Remain', 'BrexitReports']
```

You just need to read the whole file in a string and write the list as lines in a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the first items in the tuples are hashtagged, you can do:

```
data = [(u'#Brexit', 823), ..., (u'#BrexitReports', 17)]
with open('Output.txt') as f:
    for word, i in data:
        # if word.startswith('#')  # if there are non-hashtagged words
        f.write(word.lstrip('#') + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval(open('filename.txt').read())
f = open('new_data.txt', 'w')
for a, b in data:
   if a.startswith('#'):
       f.write(a[1:]+'\n')

f.close()
```